# Cannot start React app due to missing script 'start'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, react-hooks, web-frontend

I'm newbie to react js.Trying to run a simple app and getting this error and can't figure out what's wrong

```
D:\React app\react-app1>npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muralidharan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-29T08_51_37_315Z-debug-0.log
```

This is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-app1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Anything wrong with installation? or outdated version something like that?

Comment: Can you show your package.json and especially the scripts property?

Comment: I have added it in the question ,can you please look at it ?

Comment: Thank you. Then please look at the answer from @Seblor - you need at least a script for starting the application. When you call "npm start", npm looks into your package.json and tries to find a command under scripts > start. And your package.json doesn't have it

Answer (score 1):

This happens becaue you have no script called "start" in your package.json file. Here is an example of a package.json file with such script:

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
  "author": "Muralidharan",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I add these part  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js"
  }  to my package.json file ?

Comment: @Muralidharan Well it depends on the name of the entrypoint JS file. If your file is called "app.js", the script will be `"start": "node app.js"`. But otherwise that's pretty much it. `npm start` is a shorthand for `npm run start`, so you can read the documentation here : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script

Answer (score 0):

add this to your package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },
```

start is the command you need that trigger react-script to run your project
build, test and eject are other command you will need for development process